# Graphics, Import and Inset combined

Tags: graphics, import

I need to write a word on a figure, which I have saved as fig.pdf.

1) I import the pdf file to mathematica:

```
a = Import["fig.pdf"][[1]];
```

2) Following the example given in "Help":

```
Graphics[{Circle[], Inset[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {0, 0}]}]
```

I do

```
Graphics[{a, Inset[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {0, 0}]}]
```

But this does not work. How can I write a word in an imported pdf, in a position a I wish?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have problem because your variable `a` is already a graphics object. This works for me:

```
file = Export["fig.pdf", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}]]
g = First[Import[file]]
Graphics[{g[[1]], Inset[x^2 + y^2 == 1, {200, 200}]}]
```

[image]